What were the works of Tagore that Mistral commented on?
Mistral's first published collection, Desolación, contains a number of prose works in addition to her poetry. In one of them, "Commentarios a poemas de Rabindranath Tagore", Mistral wrote commentaries on three lines written by Tagore:

Sé que también amaré la muerte.
Yo me jacté entre los hombres de que te conocía...
Arranca esta florecilla.  Temo que se marchite, y se deshoje, y
caiga,  y se confunda con el polvo.

which I would translate as:

I know that I will love death too.
I boasted among men that I knew you...
Pick this little flower.   I fear that it will wither, and shed
its leaves, and fall,   and mingle with the dust.

What work, or works, of Tagore are these lines from?




And because I love this life, I know I shall love death as well.
-- Rabindranath Tagore, an untitled poem, Gitanjali (1910), #95, and Poetry Magazine, December 1912, p. 86




I boasted among men that I had known you.
-- Rabindranath Tagore, "Sit Smiling", Gitanjali (1910), #102




Pluck this little flower and take it, delay not! I fear lest it
droop and drop into the dust.
-- Rabindranath Tagore, "Flower", Gitanjali (1910), #6




Found by searching Google for tagore "love death" and tagore "boasted among men" and tagore flower wither in the dust.

Very quick work! (and a flattering degree of faith in my translation from the Spanish ;)

@ClaraDíazSanchez Well, I searched for the most distinctive thing in each one - I figured "love death" was unlikely to be phrased in any other way, while "boasted among men" and "mingle with the dust" would be longer shots if I searched for the exact phrases, although one of them did work!

The first one, "And because I love this life, I know I shall love death as well," is also from Gitanjali — # 95. See poets.org.

@PeterShor Thanks, fixed.

Thank you @PeterShor  I'm not familiar with Tagore's works - does Gitanjali refer to a single book? If so, maybe we can deduce that Mistral had it (or a Spanish translation of it) in her possession.

@ClaraDíazSanchez: Gitanjali is a single book of poems. Originally, it was in Bengali, but Tagore translated it into English (translating the title as Song Offerings). Spanish translations of it do exist, so you can deduce that Mistral either had the English translation or a Spanish translation.

Here is one Spanish translation one, but it couldn't have been the one Mistral used, because in #6, the line goes "Toma esta florcita" and not "Arranca esta florecilla." So because Mistral uses arranca and not toma, it's possible that she was working from the English translation (we need somebody who can tell us what the Bengali says).

There is a Spanish translation that uses "arranca", from 1913. But in their selection they don't include (95): https://archive.org/stream/nosotros11bianuoft/nosotros11bianuoft_djvu.txt

@PeterShor as you note in a prior answer to a different question, the English Gitanjali is not a translation of the Bengali Gitanjali.
